# PHPStorm : change color of injected language, HTML and CSS

Tags: ide, phpstorm

In PHPStorm, I'm trying to change the color of the css as an injected language, trying to make this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

As you can see, in the second one, the CSS code is colored as a string, and not as CSS language. I've already disabled all language injections but the problem remains.